# Python (2.6) ftplib didn't connect to site, but FTP worked from IE Explorer

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm not certain if I'm misunderstanding something about FTP, or if there is something funny about the site I was trying to FTP into.

When I tried:

```
import ftplib
HOST = 'www.site.org'
USER = <user name>
PASSWD = <password>
FTPConn = ftplib.FTP(HOST,USER,PASSWD)
```

the result was:

```
error:[Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host failed to respond properly
```

I next tried using ftp directly from the command window, and was similarly unable to establish a connection.

However, when I used the IE Browser and typed in the address bar:

```
ftp://USER:PASSWD@HOST
```

I was able to download files through IE explorer.

Was I doing something wrong when FTPing through ftplib, or is there some sort of security issue/feature at the site I was trying to FTP from

Comment: What's your Python version? Also, are you inside a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that IE is configured to use an FTP proxy, whereas `ftplib` is not.

Comment: Is there anything I can/should do? Or do I contact the site administrator for information on how I can attempt to configure ftplib?